# Taxonomy term page called by ajax link

Tags: drupal-7

I am testing to load taxonomy/term/1 page into a wrapper 'ajax-content', but can not figure out if this is the right thing:

```
  drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax'); 
  module_load_include('inc', 'taxonomy', 'taxonomy.pages');
  $link = array(
    '#type' => 'link',
    '#title' => t('Some Taxonomy'),
    '#href' => 'taxonomy/term/1', //'taxonomy/term/1/nojs',
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('use-ajax')),
    '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'taxonomy_term_page',
        'wrapper' => 'ajax-content',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
);

print "<div id='ajax-content'></div>" . drupal_render($link);
```

This always returns a 200 error.

Any hint would be very much appreciated.

Thanks